# authorization roles which are the same as security group but allow impersonation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, impersonation, asp.net-authorization

I have defined several security groups for example

- app_admin
- app_user

and I can manage access permissions in the application with `authorize` attribute

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\app_admin")]
```

for whole controller or single actions. In html I can use

```
if (User.IsInRole(@"DOMAIN\app_admin")) {}
```

and that is perfectly fine. But the issue I have is, how can I switch the Role for testing or bug fixing purpose ?

it is possible, somehow, for example in `global.asax` set roles, based on conditions ? for example

```
if (User.Identity.Name == "Developer_Operator")
{ User.SetRole("app_user"); }
```

Any idea ?